# How to prompt a user for a file in java using Scanner?

Tags: java, file, input

I need to know how to prompt user for a file and then be able to use the file in my program. Here is my unsuccessful attempt.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner Scanscan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input filename:");
String filename = Scanscan.nextLine();
File inputFile = new File(filename);
Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
```

I get a "File not found exception" when I try it.

Comment: What's unsuccessful about it? What kind of argument does `File` constructor accept, semantically?

Comment: Why is your attempt unsuccessful? What is wrong with it? What errors or misbehaviors do you see?

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: Did you make sure the file is in correct folder? Did you try absolute path?

Comment: What are you typing in when prompted? (what would `System.out.println(filename);` look like?)

Answer (score 4):

You get a `FileNotFoundException` because the filename the user entered doesn't exist in the system. Enter a filename that does exist, and it should work. Make sure the file you're getting is in the directory you're running the program from. Try entering the name of the java file you're working on amd see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

File does not exist. You should,

1.Check that your file is existed corresponding to your executing application.

2.Try to provide full hard path of file in your system like `"C:\\sample.txt"`